# How to splice two C# lists into one? Or maybe use a different collection type?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("Blah");
list1.Add("Bleh");
list1.Add("Blih");

List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Add("Ooga");
list2.Add("Booga");
list2.Add("Wooga");
```

Is there a method to create a third list that has `{"Blah", "Bleh", "Blih", "Ooga", "Booga", "Wooga"}` or, alternatively, change `list1` so it has the three additional elements in list2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this is the solution:

```
list1.AddRange(list2)
```

Comment: If IList<T> is used then I think Concat method can be used.

Comment: @Jenea: my previous comment was note only. Your snippet works ofcourse :)

Comment: Which is what I need, I'm using List<T>.

Comment: Oops :( I did see the other answer.

Answer (score 8):

With LINQ, you can do:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("Blah");
list1.Add("Bleh");
list1.Add("Blih");

List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Add("Ooga");
list2.Add("Booga");
list2.Add("Wooga");

var finalList = list1.Concat( list2 ).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for the best answer. LINQ is the more powerful/flexible solution for handling IEnumerables.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Union() method of a List.

Comment: Union removes duplicated items, Concats don't.

Comment: Note that Union will remove any duplicates; Concat may be preferred